# How to save and load comboBox items consisting of a string and a float value in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I am developing a small C# application that counts the number of single pieces from total weight divided by a reference weight of a single piece.
I want to choose the reference weights from a comboBox. This Reference weights consist of a Name and a float value. I already can add new reference weights to the comboBox and remove them. But I need to know how to save them. I already tried to save it to a file and tried to use application property settings but it didnt work. Could someone show me please the best way to save these comboBox Items? I just want them to be saved when program is closed (save on close) and be loaded on start.

Here is my Code:

```
    // Content item for the combo box
    private class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Value;
        public Item(string name, string value)
        {
            Name = name; Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;


        }
    }

        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();




        //Combobox Items
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item("Referenz Gewicht", "1,5"));
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item("Ticket XYZ", "2,4"));
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item("Ticket ABC", "0,7"));



}

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Display the Value property
        Item itm = (Item)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", itm.Name, itm.Value);

        //Weist ausgewählten Wert textbox2 zu.
        textBox2.Text = itm.Value;



    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item(textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text));



    }



    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If your problem is with saving data to a file why do you post this wall of unrelated code to your problem. Where is the code that tries to save the items to a file?

Comment: Its not in that code. I removed it when it didnt work... sorry

Comment: Well, you should have posted it instead. This will give us the information needed to explain the error and fix it

Comment: I will post the relevant parts of the code. sec.

Comment: I could write the combobox items to a file. But it was just a list of strings like: "stringxyz213" I think i need to split it in a string and a float value. Or how to load the comboBox then by using Strings in a File only?

Comment: comboBox

Item itm = (Item)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", itm.Name, itm.Value);

Comment: You save your items line by line in the text file. You separate the two parts of the information with a semicolon. Now you can read it back knowing this fact and splitting the line at the semicolon

Comment: use a delimiter when saving (ie, stringxyz|123  Then when you bring it back in use the Split() method and parse the second value back to a float before adding the values into your object for the combobox.

Comment: OK, i will try again. How to split the values by semicolon? It didnt work for me...

Comment: When you write you join, when you read you split

Comment: OK, I would try this here: 

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                comBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            sr.Close();


But how to split by semicolon?
Or adding a Semicolon between name and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write your items....

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Item itm in combobox1.Items)
{
   sb.AppendFormat("{0};{1}{2}", itm.Name, itm.Value, Environment.NewLine);
}
File.WriteAllText("Data.txt", sb.ToString());
```

To read your items back in the combo

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("data.txt"))
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(';');
    Item itm = new Item() { Name = parts[0], Value = parts[1]};
    combobox1.Items.Add(itm);
}
```

Consider also that your 'float' value should be a real float value and not a string property. This will introduce some complexities when you read back the value from file (need a conversion from a string on file to a float in memory) but it is the correct way to do if you are dealing with a floating value number.

A concise version using Linq

**Writing:**

```
var text = combobox1.Items.Cast<Item>()
                          .Select(x => string.Format("{0};{1}", 
                           x.Name, x.Value));
File.WriteAllText(@"data.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text));
```

**Reading:**

```
var items = File.ReadLines(@"data.txt").Select(x => x.Split(';'))
                                       .Select(k => new Item() 
                                        {Name = k[0], Value = k[1]});
combobox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

(Well it is concise, but I still prefer the verbose version for clarity)